# how to make keypresses functions repeat in processing using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get his face to turn redder every time the r key is pressed

```
def setup():
    fill(0,0,255)
    size(400,400)
    ellipse(200,200,200,200)#body
    fill(255)
    ellipse(150,125,75,75)#eyes
    ellipse(250,125,75,75)
    fill(0)
    ellipse(137,115,33,33)#inside eyes
    ellipse(240,133,33,33)
    ellipse(200,230,180,80)

def draw():
    return



def keyPressed():
    if key == "r":
        fill(1*25,0,255)
        size(400,400)
        ellipse(200,200,200,200)#head
        fill(255)
        ellipse(150,125,75,75)#eyes
        ellipse(250,125,75,75)
        fill(0)
        ellipse(137,115,33,33)#inside eyes
        ellipse(240,133,33,33)
        ellipse(200,230,180,80)
```

I'm trying to get his face to turn redder every time the r key is pressed

I expected this to change the fill on the face to change by 25 each time I press the r key

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure your question has all the information needed to give a good answer. For a start, it is unclear what framework/library you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

When the key 'r' is pressed, you are setting it to a certain color (`fill(1*25, 0, 255)`) every time. You need to make a variable that increases every time the key r is pressed, and multiply that variable by 25 in the `keyPressed()` each time.

```
numTimes = 1;
```

Then later...

```
numTimes++;
fill(numTimes*25, 0, 255)
```

Also, your code is repetitive. It would make more sense if you put the code for the person in the `draw()` and then just used the `fill()` statement once. In the `keyPressed()`, all you would need to do is:

```
numTimes++;
```